# Sent Action of UIBarButtonItem to IBAction not fired

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a View Controller on which I put a Toolbar and Bar button.That Bar button is triggered (Trigger Segue )to another View Controller + has Sent Action to Some IBAction method.Now trigger segue works properly but IBAction method is not fired on click.Please help.

Comment: Please show some **actual, relevant** code. Also, sidenote: this question is not eligible for tagging with "xcode".

Comment: I Ctrl + Drag bar button upon view controller to create push relation.And Ctrl + Drag bar button upon IBAction method to create sent Action.In connection inspector both relation shows properly.

Answer (score 0):

@Farhan Ali,

Check have you connected that barbutton properly to IBAction with help of connection inspector. Usually, while connecting to bar button items to IBAction, you have to double click on the bar button.

If every thing is connected properly,

It should look like this.

[image]