# Why not a single UIBarButton works both for Trigger segue and Sent Action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I Have posted a question a few minutes before.

[Sent Action of UIBarButtonItem to IBAction not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699478/sent-action-of-uibarbuttonitem-to-ibaction-not-fired)

In that problem When I removed Trigger segue from UIBarButton in Connection Inspector,then it works perfectly for Sent Action.Why is this?

There may be many problem scenarios in which a single bar button should works for both.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to combine an action with a segue, then use the action only. 
Create the segue in IB but do not connect it with the button but with the view controller. (Click somewehre in the background, not on a Button etc.) 
And then perform the segue programmatically from the IBAction method that you connected with the button.